# Why Does code.runnable.com Allow Me to Change a Variable's Value in Java?

Tags: java, pass-by-value

I heard that Java integers are **pass by value**, so why does the following code work in code.runnable.com?

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 0;
    number = 2;
    System.out.println(number);
  }
}
```

The code will print out **2**.

Comment: You **aren't** even calling a method. This is simple local assignment. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch not calling a method **to modify the variable**. `System.out.println` is a method and it is called.

Comment: @MikeCAT Well, so is `main`. But OP's question only includes an example with local assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet doesn't pass `number` anywhere. You're declaring a local variable and then overriding its initial value. This is perfectly legal in Java, and has nothing to do with passing by reference or by value.

Comment: The code snipped do pass `number` to `System.out.println`, so it is printed.